# How to close mongodb idle connection(active: false)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an application running on node and using the mongodb library to establish connection and closing it. But the problem is, from the mongo serverStatus() command i can see that there is still 2k+ current connections still available.

```
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 2993, "available" : 835867, "totalCreated" : 220841 }
```

and most of it are having the `active: false` status.

My questions is, is there a way for me to force close these idle connections which after some time will affect my application with an timeout error.

I tried using the `killOp()` command but these only works if there is still opid value listed in these idle connections.

Appreciate some feedback on how can handle this kind of situations.

Comment: Probably more of an issue with the actual code accessing the database. You should look at the code for usage of the `MongoClient.connect()` ( or variant according to language implemented ) and ensure that this only occurs **once** within the application code. If it's appearing multiple times, and especially if it's being implemented within request handlers of a http service then the code needs revising.

Comment: If however you are purely asking from a "database administration" point of view, then you're asking on the wrong site. As is stated within the tag info for this very tag, questions about database administration can be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com instead, as this is not a **programming** question applicable to this site. Unless you are actually asking about the code creating the connections within your application.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It's my first time here, i was not aware of dba.stackexchange, i will forward my question there.